# How can I insert null data?

Tags: java, jdbc, teradata

I want to insert null data to Teradata with JDBC connection on JAVA.
First of all I try this:

```
PreparedStatement stmt;  
String qm="Insert into db.user values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
connection= DriverManager.getConnection
             (
               "jdbc:teradata://192.xxx.x.xx/database=DBC,tmode=ANSI,charset=UTF8","user","passw0rd"             ); 
stmt = connection.prepareStatement(qm); 
//some code here to open while loop 
   stmt.setObject(i,null); // This isnt working with Terada JDBC. It is working for Oracle and MSSQL JDBC   
//and I finish my code
```

And after, that I tried this instead of `stmt.setObject(i,null);` :

`stmt.setNull(i,rsmd.getColumnType(i),rsmd.getColumnTypeName(i));` 
`rsmd.getColumnType(i)`     is equal to 97
`rsmd.getColumnTypeName(i)` is equal to DATE

Yes it is true my field is DATE.

But it gives this ERROR:
`ERROR : [Teradata JDBC Driver] [TeraJDBC 14.10.00.17] [Error 857] [SQLState HY000] Two different data types are being set for parameter 17 (449 & 749)`

How can I fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically if you wish to `INSERT` a `NULL` value into `ColC` I would suggest using the following method with your `INSERT ... VALUES` statement:

```
INSERT (ColA, ColB, ColD, ColE) VALUES (1000, 'Testing Null', 1.00, DATE '2013-06-30);
```

Teradata will take the absence of the column in the `INSERT` statement to place either the pre-defined `DEFAULT` value or `NULL` for the column.

What if you try the following:

```
stmt.SetNull(i,Types.NULL)
```

Comment: thanks for reply , But I want to use preparestatament in JDBC. So I dont have a change to use your method because I dont know which column is null

Answer (score 1):

I used in the past the setNull(i, Types.#field type#) in a custom DB layer for TD.

However if you search the codes returned in the exception you'll find that they represent a Date and a Varchar, as if, at the same position, you sometimes pass a Date type and sometimes a Varchar.

Are you by chance passing not null dates as Date-like strings (e.g. "2015-08-18"), and not as java.sql.Date objects?

If that's the case you should change the code to use java.sql.Date objects and this will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround for this issue is to cast the NULL to be a VARCHAR, so that it is compatible.

```
INSERT INTO XYA(PKEY,REF_KEY) VALUES(2,cast(null as varchar(10)));
```

Comment: thanks for ansering. I am using JDBC connection.So I need to use SetObject or SetNull function